# Totem won't play DVDs (16.10)

Tags: dvd, totem

This is a new install of 16.10, a couple of weeks old. I can play DVDs using VLC, but not in Totem. When I start playback, I get the following error:

```
** Message: Missing plugin: gstreamer|1.0|totem|DVD source|urisource-dvd (DVD source)
** Message: Automatic missing codec installation not supported (helper script missing)

(totem:24090): Totem-WARNING **: Failed to reset the playback rate to 1.0
```

I do have the `totem-plugins` package, and `totem-plugins-extra` installed. In the plugin list, I see nothing about codecs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install `ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Open terminal and type in these two commands one by one:

`sudo apt update 
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

It is a meta-package that installs:
Support for MP3 and unencrypted DVD playback
Microsoft TrueType core fonts
Flash plugin
codecs for common audio and video files

Comment: Yay for misleading warning messages. I thought the installer had already installed enough of this non-free stuff for me, but clearly not.

Comment: Does not help in Ubuntu 20.04